# Date is getting subtracted 5:30 hours from the date in the response from spring-boot application

Tags: spring, reactjs, date, spring-boot

I have developed a **spring boot** application(Back end) and **reactjs**(Front End). In reactjs front end - **Date** is getting **subtracted** **5:30 Hours** from the data which is there in the response.

See the below screenshots for reference.

How can i solve this problem?

In Database i can see them as:

[image]

We can see that dateOfBirth fileds in spring-boot application when i print them.

[image]

But when i logged them in console:

[image]

Comment: please , post your JS code

Comment: Actually i just did console.log for the response. So, i don't think any need to post js code.

Comment: what is shift value for your current timezone? I guess it's 5 hours and 30 minutes, is not it?

Comment: Yes, it's 5 hours and 30 minutes...

Comment: @ManikantaB it prints them in UTC0, you want them print as UTC-5:30. I suggest you use the momentjs library for your react.

Comment: @Kerry Gougeon Ok, how can we use moment for react, any help is appreciated.